# Launching a second spark-shell kills the first one

Tags: apache-spark

I have a micro test cluster, 3 nodes, 1core/1G per node, using standalone cluster manager. 
When I launch a second spark-shell while the first is running, the latter gets killed abruptly. 
I would like to understand the underlying mechanism. 
Standalone Cluster manager is supposed to have a preemptive FIFO approach to resource acquisition. 
To my understanding, the second spark-shell should be the one to be kicked out due to resources not being sufficient. Why is it that the existing spark-shell process is the one to be aborted?

Comment: I think you are opening spark-shell same directory or folder.. try open in different folders.

Comment: @Srinivas this suggestion does not hold, unfortunately. This makes no sense. I can see no reason why this would be a valid cause